# How are serializer discriminator groups used for exclusion policy?

Tags: php, symfony, jmsserializerbundle

The [serializer documentation](https://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/reference/annotations#discriminator) states only with this single sentence that discriminator groups can be use with exclusion policy, however, the [exclusion strategies documentation](https://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/cookbook/exclusion_strategies) doesn't explain how to do so.  How can they be used?

> @Discriminator This annotation allows serialization/deserialization
>   of relations which are polymorphic, but where a common base class
>   exists. The @Discriminator annotation has to be applied to the least
>   super type:
>
> ```
> /**
>  * @Discriminator(field = "type", disabled = false, map = {"car": "Car", "moped": "Moped"}, groups={"foo", "bar"})
>  */
> abstract class Vehicle { }
> class Car extends Vehicle { }
> class Moped extends Vehicle { }
> ```
>
> **Note: groups is optional and is used as exclusion policy.**

Answer (score 0):

`groups` is used to include or exclude the `field` only (not the sub entity).

Use it like this:

```
use JMS\Serializer\SerializationContext;

$serializer->serialize(new Moped(), 'json', SerializationContext::create()->setGroups(array('foo')));
```

Comment: Thanks Thomas.  I understand how a group can be added to a property.  But what is the purpose of adding them such as `@Discriminator(..., groups={"foo", "bar"})`?

Comment: discriminator is a property, like any other class variables.

Comment: Meaning that `@Discriminator(field = "type", ... groups={"foo", "bar"})` would only include the discriminator with property name "type" when "foo" or "bar" is passed to  `SerializationContext::create()->setGroups()`?  That makes perfect sense!  Unfortunately, I just tried it and it had no effect.  On an off chance, I also looked for method `setDiscriminatorGroup()`, but no such method.  Have you ever used it?  Thanks